# How to restrict access to source in excel list Data validation?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to restrict users from not changing data source in excel data validation for lists?

Comment: Can you simply lock the cells the validation is assigned to?

Comment: @Bigtree Locking the cells will restrict users from selecting and/or changing the value

Comment: You can enter the list manually rather than entering it in a range of cells.  The user could still change the list if they knew how.  Would this be acceptable?

Comment: @PortlandRunner This is the main requirement, that users should not be able to change data source

Comment: Please clarify why @Bigtree suggestion wouldn't work then... Your drop down is in another cell that's not locked right? So you would only lock the cells that have the list items.

Comment: @PortlandRunner I missunderstoon Bigtree's suggestion. I thought he meant to lock the cell that has the Data validation

Answer (score 0):

You could put all the data that needs to be secured in an other Worksheet and than Hide it.
The hidden Worksheet can't be accessed manually just through VBA code.